# Removing desktop picture on CircleCI

Tags: circleci, macos-mojave

We run some localization checks by taking screenshots in CircleCI.  We compare new screenshots with images taken from what we expect - any differences are flagged.

The problem with CircleCI is MacOS Mojave changes the background on the time of day, so some of the images which contain part of the background are constantly flagged as different.

I have tried running all the commands I could find to remove or change the background:

- via osascripts - it times out as I believe Mojave has the permission
  popup.  I haven't found a way to bypass it.
- via sqllite - these commands don't seem to work with Mojave.

Ultimately this might not be exactly what CCI is built for, but it is necessary for us to run these tests in CI.  Has anyone been able to disable desktop pictures?  (Using xcode 11.1 image, which is MacOs Mojave)

Comment: I'm not sure how to stop the wallpaper from changing. Another option might be to crop the screenshot, removing the section with the wallpaper showing?

Comment: We mostly do, but some require to show the menubar, or popup menus etc.  It can be quite problematic to trim away all the background.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I was able to get around this with a bit of a hack.  CCI support were not helpful and unable to provide a solution, so I found opening safari was the only app I could find that would open mostly full screen.  This then became the background.

Steps

1. Remove the dock, so any corner gaps still don't show the background
2. Open safari.app
3. There is still a thin sliver just above safari, but some python to put a block of solid colour there works for me.

Comparisons are then equal.

Code to do so:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 1000 && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE && killall Dock            
defaults write com.apple.dock tilesize -float 1; killall Dock
open -a safari http://invalid.website # Not a real website, but shows an error.  Otherwise create your own html page to open
```